# Laplace Transform of exponential of a function

Tags: laplace-transform

Is there a general expression for laplace transform of exponential of a function? i.e.

$\mathcal{L}\left(e^{x\left(t\right)}\right)$

where x is a function of t and the transformation is from the time domain variable t to the frequeny domain variable s. I can approximate it with taylor's series for a given x, but I would like to know if a general, exact formula for it exists. More specifically, I would like to express the time-domain system

$y(t)=e^{x(t)}$

as

$Y\left(s\right)=T\left(s\right)X\left(s\right)$

where

$X\left(s\right)=$ Laplace transform of x(t),

$Y\left(s\right)=$ Laplace transform of y(t) and

$T\left(s\right)=$ Transfer function of the system.

Comment: What type function $x(t)=t^{t^t}$.!

Comment: The type of function is unknown. I don't know if a general formula is even possible or not, which is why i am asking.

Comment: You must restrict the function to have Laplace transform. For instance $e^{t^2}$ hasn't Laplace transform.

Answer (score 1):

There are some special cases of the Laplace transforms of composite functions. See [this document](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjK1f3SxN_WAhUFthoKHQUlDSoQFgg6MAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fmcom%2F1968-22-101%2FS0025-5718-68-99884-0%2FS0025-5718-68-99884-0.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1jJ1ry1QJKF53z2W99_U3d) and [this one](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=0ahUKEwjK1f3SxN_WAhUFthoKHQUlDSoQFghxMAg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.emis.de%2Fjournals%2FHOA%2FIJMMS%2FVolume2_1%2F239852.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1KgHvZTqn0b2VN-jsL93I4).